# Hyperparameter optimisation in Python with a separate validation set

Tags: machine-learning, python, random-forest

I am trying to optimise the hyper parameters of a [random forest regressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor) in Python.

I have 3 separate datasets: train/validate/test. Therefore, rather than using a cross validation method I want to use the specific validation set to tune the hyperparameters, i.e. the "First Approach" described in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126811/order-between-using-validation-training-and-test-sets).

Now, sklearn has some nice inbuilt methods for hyperparameter optimisation using cross validation (e.g. [this tutorial](https://pierpaolo28.github.io/blog/blog25/)), but what about if I want to tune my hyperparameters with a specific validation set? Is it still possible to use a method like [RandomizedSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible with `cv` option. As the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) suggests, one of the possible inputs is an iterable of train/test index tuples:

> An iterable yielding (train, test) splits as arrays of indices.

So, a list of size one with train and validation indices packed as a tuple would be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should just have some wording clarified:

**'Validation set'**

A validation-set is used to evaluate your model on a *unseen* set of data i.e data *not* used for training. This is to simulate how your model would behave on new data. We use the validation-set to tune our hyper-parameters such as number of trees, max-depths etc. and chose the hyper-parameters which works best on the validation set.

**'Cross-validate'**

When you CV (cross-validate) with, say, 5 folds you divide your data into 5 sets where set [1,2,3,4] are used for traning, and set 5 is used for validation. Then you use [2,3,4,5] for training and use set 1 for validation - you repeat this untill all sets (i.e 5 times when using 5 fold) have been used as a validation-set and then you would average your 5 validation-score e.g accuracy to get one score which you want to (often) maximize.

**Answer**

So, to answer your question; yes, you can use GridSearchCV on your validation-set but that wouldn't often be the case since. You would often do one of the following:

a) Use a (i.e one) validation-set to tune your hyper-parameters against, as explained in "Validation set"

b) Use all your data i.e train+validation as one data-set and then run a, say, 5-fold grid-CV search as explained in "Cross-validate"