# how to use an explicit validation set with predefined split fold?

Tags: python-3.x, validation, scikit-learn, cross-validation, train-test-split

I have explicit train, test and validation sets as 2d arrays:

```
X_train.shape
(1400, 38785)
X_val.shape
(200, 38785)
X_test.shape
(400, 38785)
```

I am tuning the alpha parameter and need advice about how I can use the predefined validation set in it:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, PredefinedSplit

nb = MultinomialNB()
nb.fit(X_train, y_train)

params = {'alpha': [0.1, 1, 3, 5, 10,12,14]}
# how to use on my validation set?
# ps = PredefinedSplit(test_fold=?)

gs = GridSearchCV(nb, param_grid=params, cv = ps,  return_train_score=True, scoring='f1')

gs.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

My results are as following so far.

```
# on my validation set, alpha = 5
gs.fit(X_val, y_val)
print('Grid best parameter', gs.best_params_)
Grid best parameter:  {'alpha': 5}

# on my training set, alpha = 10
Grid best parameter:  {'alpha': 10}
```

I have read the following questions and documentation yet I am not sure how to use PredefinedSplit() in my case. Thank you.

[Order between using validation, training and test sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126811/order-between-using-validation-training-and-test-sets)

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#predefined-fold-splits-validation-sets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your desired outcome by merging `X_train` and `X_val`, and passing `PredefinedSplit` a list of labels, with `-1` indicating training data and `1` indicating validation data. IE,

```
X = np.concatenate((X_train, X_val))
y = np.concatenate((y_train, y_val))
ps = PredefinedSplit(np.concatenate((np.zeros(len(x_train) - 1, np.ones(len(x_val))))

gs = GridSearchCV(nb, param_grid=params, cv = ps,  return_train_score=True, scoring='f1')

gs.fit(X, y)  # not X_train, y_train
```

However, unless there is very a good reason for you holding out a separate validation set, you will likely have less overfitting if you use k-fold cross validation for your hyperparameter tuning rather than using a dedicated validation set.

Comment: you see, it is a university assignment and I am given the three sets.  I am trying different models for a sentiment analysis of movie reviews, and so far the Naive Bayes gives me the best f1 score... far better than neural networks.  I was just wondering where the validation set might come in the Naive Bayes model.

Comment: apologies. I have tried a = np.zeros(len(X_vect_train.astype(object)))-1 and b = np.ones(len(X_vect_val)) and then, np.concatenate([a,b]). and it works!  it is just that this workaround is not very clear.     Still not sure why we have to convert them into the numpy ones and zeros arrays for this to work.

Comment: `GridSearchCV` accepts only one training set, it does not accept a validation set, so you need to provide a CV splitter. 

`PredefinedSplitCV` takes is [a CV splitter](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.PredefinedSplit.html?highlight=predefinedsplit#sklearn.model_selection.PredefinedSplit) that takes a list of labels to pre-define different validation folds. `-1` indicates training data that should never be used for validation.